# Can PDF changes be reversed?

Tags: pdf, adobe

If I use Adobe PDF pro to change a text number on a PDF, then I email the edited PDF to someone, what are they able to see in terms of my changes? My understanding is that they can see in the metadata that it was edited and by whom it was edited, but can they see what element was changed and the previous versions?

I have sometimes seen PDF files increase in size after being edited, and I am wondering if this is due to the history of the document being saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how exactly the changes are applied. In addition to simply saving the new state of the pdf from scratch, the pdf standard also knows the concept of *incremental updates*. Using this technique changes are appended after the end of the original file.

If changes are applied using an incremental update, the exact state of the previous revision can be retrieved by simply cutting of the incremental update data.

I've seen Adobe Reader using either technique. Incremental updates are always used in case of signed files (including files merely signed with a usage rights signature!) but I think Adobe also uses incremental updates in some other cases.

---

There also are other situations in which original content remains even though saving from scratch is used:

PDFs don't only know the canvases of each page and annotation, they also know independent ones, form XObjects. Sections of a form XObject can be added to another canvas by reference.

If such a form XObject is referenced from multiple other canvases and then is edited in the context of one of these referencing canvases (e.g. in the course of editing a specific page it is used on), usually a copy of that XObject is created and edited which then is referenced from that one canvas while all other referencing canvases still reference the original version.

Someone diving into the pdf internals in such a case can find the original, unedited variant.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What would be the best way to identify whether someone could find my original PDF by diving into the internals?

Comment: diving into them yourself. Adobe Acrobat is not open source. Thus, you cannot know beforehand how exactly it will execute your changes, in particular as there are so many ways the content of your start documents can be structured. Pdf by design is not a format to edit easily and deterministically, so even though there is pdf editing software, never trust it to remove information for sure.

Comment: By the way a similar warning holds for other formats and editors, too, all binary formats actually. Only if you have a format you trivially understand (pure text; with the proper knowledge also html and similar mark-up and mark-down languages, tex  or latex sources, etc) you have a chance to really be sure to succeed when you try to remove content for good.